# I can not pass by reference my node

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference, c11

I dont want create general *head node and I want to pass by reference and chance my data but although create new node for next node I cant reach my new node on main.
İf I look n1.next in main I see it is null.Why ?What is wrong ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};

void add(struct node** head,int data){
    struct node * tmp = *head;

    while(tmp != NULL){
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    tmp = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    tmp->data= data;
    tmp->next=NULL;
}

int main()
{
    struct node n1;

    n1.data=5;
    n1.next=NULL;

    add(&(n1.next),15);
    printf("%d",n1.next->data);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please point out the line where you assign a non-null pointer to `*head`?

Comment: I dont have head pointer so I try I pass by reference .I dont want use head pointer.All code here

Comment: [don't cast malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a head pointer, are you trying to pass in the last `next` pointer in the list, and then update that to point to your new node?  If so, `add()` should be

```
void add(struct node** head, int data) {
    struct node* p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
    p->data = data;
    p->next = NULL;

    *head = p;
}
```